# TYPO3 ActionController without authentication

Tags: php, typo3

I am implementing a TYPO3 plugin with actions in an `ActionController` class.
However, the `ActionController` base class seems to enforce authentication.
In my use case, I, however, do not want authentication, since that particular controller renders a page that should be publicly accessible.
How can I deactivate authentication in such a controller?

```php
<?php

namespace Homeinfo\SysMon2\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

use Generator;

use Homeinfo\hwdb\Domain\Model\Deployment;
use Homeinfo\hwdb\Domain\Repository\DeploymentRepository;
use Homeinfo\hwdb\Domain\Repository\SystemRepository;

use Homeinfo\SysMon2\Domain\Repository\CheckResultsRepository;
use Homeinfo\SysMon2\SystemWithCheckResults;

class UnauthenticatedAccess extends ActionController
{
    public function systemDetailsAction()
    {
        //$customerId = $this->request->getArgument('customer');
        $customerId = 1030020;
        $deploymentRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)
            ->get(DeploymentRepository::class);
        $deployments = iterator_to_array($deploymentRepository->findByCustomerId($customerId));
        $systemRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)
            ->get(SystemRepository::class);
        $deploymentIds = [];
        
        foreach ($deployments as &$deployment)
            $deploymentIds[] = $deployment->id;

        $systems = iterator_to_array($systemRepository->findByDeploymentIds($deploymentIds));
        $checkResultsRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)
            ->get(CheckResultsRepository::class);
        $systemIds = [];
            
        foreach ($systems as $system)
            $systemIds[] = $system->id;

        $checkResults = iterator_to_array($checkResultsRepository->findLastMonthBySystems($systemIds));
        $systemsWithCheckResults = iterator_to_array(
            SystemWithCheckResults::fromSystemsDeploymentsAndCheckResults($systems, $deployments, $checkResults)
        );
        $this->view->assign('systemsWithCheckResults', $systemsWithCheckResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you in frontend or backend context?

Comment: No, the frontend action controller does not enforce authentication by default. Are you sure you have made the actual page this renders on, available publicly?

Comment: @CBroe OMG. I entirely missed that. It was indeed the page settings. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a final answer: By default, the authentication happens on a page level or on a content element level. It is therefore not possible to unprotect a certain action as the controller is not even called if the usergroups don't match.

If you need certain actions only for logged in users, you need to take care about the check yourself and fetch the current user on your own.

Be aware of caching! If the plugin is cacheable, it is on a usergroup(combination) level and *not* on a user level. Most of the time it makes sense to make the whole plugin uncacheable.